# What is standard reference to lookup the scope of calls by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

First of all here is a snippet of some code that made me feel not quite sure about how reference identifiers work:

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;    
void theUgly (int *z, int *q)
{
    if(q == z)
        *z=3;
    /*else*/
        *z=6;
};

void theNice (int &y, int *q)
{
    theUgly(&y, q);
};

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    theNice(x, &x);
    cout << x << endl; 
}
```

I wasn't sure to expect output be `3` or `5` since I wasn't sure about reference running with 2 identifiers having the 2 address, what seemed odd to me, or just leaving this handling to the user.

But I actually got `6` as output, what now lets me assume there is *compiled in* some kind of atomic operations.

I tried to find the exact documentation about this behavior in my "n3690" copy of the c++11 standard. I found the most part I was able to look up was dealing with capture reference declarations or other stuff named `capture` or lambda expressions. But just a handful of times I was able to `strg`+`f` "by reference" in it. And nothing really seemed to me like explaining the mechanic that describes the behaving of my snippet.

So my question simply is: Where exactly in the c++11 standard it is described, how a program has to handle the parameters and scopes, as happened for my test snippet?

**EDIT:**
After noticing and adding the missing `else` the snippet puts out what I would expect. But since I wasn't able to find any information about the behaving of passes by refference in the standard docs, The question remains as it is, independed of the snippet.

Comment: Your edits make me feel sloppy tobi. but thanks!

Comment: Why would you **not** expect 6 as the output? After all, it’s the last assignment, regardless of whether a new address were assigned to the reference.

Comment: `*z=6` is the last assignment executed. Why do you expect something else?

Comment: ah *facepalm* let me quickly fix it!

Comment: sloppy indeed you should feel, I only fixed what was marked by as typo by the spellchecker :P

Comment: Why it is unclear what I'm asking? I asked for a reference to the § of the standard that describes how passes by reference behave.

Comment: well, "independent of the snippet" the question is not clear at all. If you have `int& x = y`, then `&x` should be the same as `&y`. What isnt clear?

Comment: @tobi303: clear isn't to me under what name I can look this up in the iso doc

Comment: sorry but I dont know what you want to look up. Thats just how references work, i might be wrong, but the fact that you pass them around in functions like in your snippet is rather irrelevant, because a reference to `x` is still a reference to `x` whether `x` itself is in scope or not.

Comment: @tobi303: I'm not saying you are wrong. I just want to read it up in the iso draft. as they are the guys who maintain the standard, not you.

Comment: @Zaibis 8.3.2 §3 explains what tobi303 said, I'm not quite sure why do you need to look up why `int&x = y` then `&x == &y`.

Comment: @PcAF: Why I shouldn't look anything up, when I have not read any primary source information about it yet?!

Comment: 8.3.2/1 has a note saying "A reference can be thought of as a name of an object." So you are basically looking for the information, why `*x==*x` and I doubt you will find anything on this specifically in the standard ;)

Comment: @tobi303: "[dcl.init.ref]" was what I asked for. nothing else :)

Comment: then honestly I dont understand the question, because there is only this one chapter about references in the standard

Comment: @Zaibis Standard isn't for explaining things, it just says *what shall happen* and *what shall not happen*. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `*z=6;` is not in an `else` clause. This assignment is executed in any case.

Actually, `g++-5.3 -O2 -std=c++14` transforms `theNice` into:

```
void theNice (int &y, int *q)
{
    y = 6;
};
```

---

As for the behaviour of references as functions arguments:

1. **`[dcl.fct]`**: function parameter declaration
2. **`[dcl.init.ref]`**: initialization of references
3. **`[expr.call]`**: initialization of function parameters with argument expressions

In short: They behave like local references and reference (alias) the (l)value they are bound to. Calling a function which expects a (lvalue) reference with a (l)value binds that reference to the provided value in the scope of the callee.